# Facebook Duckling - server error: parsing on input

Tags: facebook, haskell-stack, duckling

I am trying to run the Duckling server through my Windows 11 laptop and its giving this error.

I tried looking at the github page of [Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) and followed the instructions to run the server. It initially built it in a wrong format. Soon, I landed up in a [Rasa Forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/steps-to-run-use-duckling-in-window/11801/7) which stated I should try the following [changes](https://github.com/botpress/duckling/pull/1/files). Now, when I do the necessary changes I am getting this error.

```
exe\ExampleMain.hs:17:29: error: parse error on input `qualified'
   |
17 | import Data.ByteString.Lazy qualified as LBS
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^


Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.

       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the following errors:

       [S-7011]
       While building package duckling-0.2.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
       C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_sDt42OhJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4.exe --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work\dist\29cc6475 build lib:duckling exe:custom-dimension-example exe:duckling-example-exe exe:duckling-expensive exe:duckling-regen-exe exe:duckling-request-sample --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

My main aim is to use it for entity detection for my chatbot application. Also I didn't make any other changes from what is given in the above "changes" link.